# Use YouTube API in Discord Bot

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, bots, discord.py

I was thinking about a Discord Bot that gives you a sub role if you are sub of a YouTube Channel using YouTube API but I really don't know how to use YouTube API in my Bot so my Question is how could I add YouTube Data API to my Bot ?

Comment: According to [this article](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/7280745?hl=en#:~:text=You%20can%20see%20a%20list,set%20to%20private%20by%20default.) Youtube Subscriber data cannot be fetched as such. However in server settings under integrations, there's an option to sync subscribers and assign them roles. It's worth looking into.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot actually give a role to the subscribers in a server as discord and youtube's databases are not connected anyhow, so you cannot get a discord user which is a subscriber of a specific youtube channel. However, you can use [`google-api-python-client`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) in your bot to connect it with youtube and get info about a specific channel or search a video, you will require a [`youtube API key`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) to do so.

Heres how you can code it -

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

@client.command()
async def ytsearch(ctx, query: str):
    youtube = build("youtube", "v3", developerKey=YT_Key)
    search_response = youtube.search().list(q=<query>, part="id,snippet", maxResults=5).execute()
    await ctx.send(search_response) # It will send the data in a .json format.
```